# The Sound of Latin

Tags: reference-request, latin

Hopefully this isn't considered off topic. Are there any audio-video works of art or linguistics that have highly accurate (based on our best reconstructions) depictions of Classical Latin speech in terms of pronunciation and prosody?

Comment: One-page [summary of Latin pronunciation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinPronunciation.pdf) from freshman etymology.

Comment: It appears that I was unclear (and I completely forgot about this question when I was out of town). I was wondering if there were any audio-video works with accurate representations. Movies, radios, etc.

Comment: @JustinOlbrantz, "audio-video works with accurate representations"??? I hope you realize that the way we read Latin is an educated, more or less accurate approximation (**reconstruction**). Nothing more. I highly doubt any reputable scholar would agree to produce such media materials.

Comment: [This illustrates Classical vs. Ecclesiastical Latin.](http://la.raycui.com/)

Answer (score 8):

*Vox Latina: A Guide to the Pronunciation of Classical Latin* by W.Sydney Allen is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to *Vox Latina*, Edgar Sturtevant's *The Pronunciation of Greek and Latin* is also helpful.